# Текст в графике

Tags: pascal

Доброго времени суток!

Рисую число '1234' с помощью `OutTextXY(x,y,'1234');` Хочется затереть, например, цифру 3. Где она - узнать труда не составляет. Допустим, `(x1,y1)` - её координаты.  Хотелось бы лениво вывести символ какой-нибудь в это место, чтобы затёрлось немного. Не подскажете - какой? =)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выведите тот же символ ('3') цветом фона.

Comment: Пробел попробовал... Не хочет.
А вот цветом фона, и в правду =)
Не подумал что-то... Спасибо!

Comment: поправил ответ

Comment: А символа в Ascii нету кстати который бы затёр (ну именно для графики)... 

Все попробовал =)

Comment: Есть `#219`. Смотрите [таблицу](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/).

Comment: Не, всмысле чтобы не меняя цвет. Типа пробел поставить.
В консоли если выводить символ пробел поверх существующего, то он его зарисует.
А в графике не хочет.

Comment: @mike_live графический режим ничего не знает про символы, которые он выводит, поэтому так сделать не получится.